# while in promise ( fs readstream )

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, fs

I make a script for auto upload backup file (on Backblaze) ...

Making a script that loads the full file into a `const`, split the string and upload each part when the file size increases(from 1 to more than 3gb) my script crashes.

I tried to rewrite the script fully async.

I write this :

```js
async getFileInfoAndUploadPart(path, sizeChunk = 1024) {
    const info = {
      sha1: null,
      size: 0,
      partNumber: 0,
      partSha1: {},
    };
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const shasumGlobal = crypto.createHash('sha1');
      console.log(path, sizeChunk);
      const input = fs.createReadStream(path);
      input.on('readable', () => {
        console.log('1');
        let chunk;
        while ((chunk = input.read(sizeChunk)) !== null) {
          console.log('2');
          const tempShasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
          shasumGlobal.update(chunk);
          tempShasum.update(chunk);
          info.partNumber += 1;
          info.partSha1[info.partNumber] = tempShasum.digest('hex');
        }
        console.log('3');
        info.sha1 = shasumGlobal.digest('hex');
        resolve(info);
      });
    });
  }
```

But the promise resolves before the `while` :/
What are the right methods for making this while finish before return my promise?

( i plant to call an async function in this while for uploading each part)

**Edit**

Finaly i use this methods :

```js
    async getFileInfoAndUploadPart(path, sizeChunk = 1024, fileId = 'xxx') {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const info = {
        fileId: fileId,
        sha1: null,
        size: 0,
        partNumber: 0,
        partSha1: {},
      };
      const input = fs.createReadStream(path, { highWaterMark: sizeChunk });
      const shasumGlobal = crypto.createHash('sha1');

      input.on('data', async dataChunk => {
        const shasumPart = await crypto.createHash('sha1');
        await shasumPart.update(dataChunk);
        await shasumGlobal.update(dataChunk);

        info.partNumber += 1;
        info.partSha1[info.partNumber] = shasumPart.digest('hex');
      });

      input.on('end', () => {
        info.sha1 = shasumGlobal.digest('hex');
        resolve(info);
      });
    });
  }
```

EDIT 2:

The code above didn't work well ...

In first place, you need to make the stream pause when you play with the data, and resume the stream when you can handle the next part...

Second bug:
If you try this code with a 10 oct file, and use a 5 oct chunk...

> You trigg the 'data' event first time => ok
>
> You trigg the 'data' event second time => ok
>
> You trigg the 'end' event => ok ...

But if you want to split the stream in 3 part ( Math.ceil(fileSize/chunkSize) => 4 + 4 + 2 , only the last part need to be shorter )

> You trigg the 'data' event first time => ok
>
> You trigg the 'data' event second time => ok
>
> You trigg the 'data' event third time, but
>   you reach the end of the stream , so you trigg the 'end' event at the
>   same time ...

I didn't find any solution for trigg 'end' event only after my 'data' logique is finish ...

So i think i pre-calculate the number of chunk , and implemente my 'end' logic in the 'data' event when i'am on the last chunk ...

Comment: your promise is not resolving before while loop ends. there may be a situation that your code inside promise callback fails thus promise may reject, not resolve. try to add `.catch(err => console.log(err))` to result that returned by  `getFileInfoAndUploadPart ` function and inspect what error is

Comment: The script crash because i call `shasumGlobal.update(chunk);` after the `shasumGlobal.digest('hex');`
( and in my console i see the `1`, `3` , and the return of my function ...  then crash in the while .... ( never see the `2` ... )

Comment: We support iterating streams directly with async iterators in Node, consider using it with `for await`

Answer (score 0):

```js
async getFileInfoAndUploadPart(path, sizeChunk = 1024, fileId = 'xxx') {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const stats = fs.statSync(path);
      const info = {
        fileId: fileId,
        sha1: null,
        size: 0,
        partNumber: 0,
        partNumberTheoretical: Math.ceil(stats.size/sizeChunk),
        partSha1: {},
      };

      const input = fs.createReadStream(path, { highWaterMark: sizeChunk });
      const shasumGlobal = crypto.createHash('sha1');

      input.on('data', async dataChunk => {
        input.pause();
        const shasumPart = crypto.createHash('sha1');
        shasumPart.update(dataChunk);
        shasumGlobal.update(dataChunk);
        info.partNumber += 1;
        info.partSha1[info.partNumber] = shasumPart.digest('hex');

        // force passe copy of info obj.
        // await this.uploadWithRetry(dataChunk, { ...info }, parameters.getConfig('maxRetry'), parameters.getConfig('waitBeforeRetry'));

        await this.debug().then(() => {
          console.log({ ... info });
        });
        input.resume();

        if (info.partNumber === info.partNumberTheoretical) {
          console.log('end');
          info.sha1 = shasumGlobal.digest('hex');
          resolve(info);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

PS: debug is this function

```js
async debug(time = 1000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, time);
    });
  };
```